# Can a person attain moksha involuntarily?

Tags: scripture, moksha

Most of the people practice, in their lifetime, some or other paths established by scriptures to get moksha. Some may use rama nama, some may use yoga, some may use jnana marga, etc.,

Each path may take a lot of time and constant practice. After that, the aspirant can get moksha according to the scriptures.

Are there any instances in scriptures that a person gets moksha involuntarily? That is, the aspirant didn't consciously perform any practice for moksha, but got moksha.

Comment: Ramakrishna has a parable about a seeker who got Moksha seemingly without effort.  Ramakrishna said he had done the effort in previous births @hanugm

Comment: I kinda agree with @SK on this. 'There is no free lunch'. Dharma+Artha+Kama+Moksha are the 4 purusharthas. If it seems like someone is getting something for free, it means someone else is paying for it, or they paid for it already. Bhagavan is impartial, so he doesn't randomly repay someone's karmic debt. Acharyas on other hand, don't have to play by impartiality rule. They can recommend that someone get Moksha simply if they ask for it, and sometimes even if they didn't consciously ask for it. But in all cases, they have done Punya in previous lives to get to this stage.